# vee-validate 3.x. validate "required value if only another value is null"

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

vee-validate 3.x.

I want to validate "required value if only another value is null".

Refereing "Cross Field Validation",
I tried to create a such a validator.

```
        validate: function (value, another) {
            return another.value != null || value != null;
        }
```

but the validate function is not called when `value` is null.

how to create such a validator?
or how to do that the function is called when `value` is null?

Thanks for reading my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bootstrap-vue 2.x, I sovled the problem by myself.

```
 <validation-provider name="REQUIRE_ONE"
    :rules='{ required: another == null}' v-slot='v-slot-1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone is using `ValidationProvider`

`fieldModel1` will be required if `fieldModel2` is null or empty string

```
<ValidationProvider
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  vid="fieldModel1"
  :rules="{
    required: !fieldModel2 || fieldModel2.length === 0,
  }"
  name="Your field name"
>
```